# Rails fields_for with empty model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am using `fields_for` like so (pseudo code)

```
fields_for(@model) do |f|
  f.text_field :foo
end
```

The problem is that sometimes `foo` contains the model data and sometimes it doesn't, which throws an error.

`undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @model
  fields_for(@model) do |f|
    f.text_field :foo
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Or (this however should be done in the controller)

```
fields_for(@model || Model.new) do |f|
  f.text_field :foo
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still want the field to be rendered so they can add some data if it doesn't exist, or change it if it does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would this look in the private parameters method? Eg: `params.require(:bar).permit(:foo)`

Comment: It would be sth like: `params.require(:parent_form).permit(model: :foo)